# On Implementing Wide Resnet architecture

Tags: conv-neural-network, deep-residual-networks

While I was working on implementing the wide resnet architecture, I had one main question regarding the calculation of N according to the paper [wide resnet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07146):

[image]

In their implementation I found that N is calculated as:

```
N = (n - 4) / 6 # n is the number of layers
```

But I don't understand why do we subtract 4 from n?

Does n reflects the number of layers in general, including conv layers, or it is the number of conv layers only?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that by using the same table as above, i.e., having 3 groups of conv operations (conv2-3-4); then the 4 subtracted from `n` in the my question refers to: conv1 + fc_layer (for the output) + 2 conv layers (for the projection shortcut) => 4 conv layers